# Django: Is there a better way to bold the current page link

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a base.html template that contains a list of links.

Example:

```
   <div id="sidebar1">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/" title="">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="/stuff/" title="" class="current">Stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/" title="">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/" title="">Contact Me</a></li>
    </div>
```

Then I have in my views.py a definition for each of index.html, stuff.html, about.html and contact.html.  Each of those templates simply derive from a base.html template and set their own respective titles and contents.

My question is about the above /stuff I have a class="current".

I'd like to make the current page that I'm on have that class attribute.

I could set a different variable in each view like current_page="about" and then do a compare in the template with `{% ifequal %}` in each class element of each link , but that seems like duplicating work (because of the extra view variable).

Is there a better way?  Maybe if there is a way to get the view function name that the template was filled from automatically I would not need to set the extra variable?  Also it does seem like a lot of ifequals.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an elegant way to do this, which I copied from somewhere and I only wish I could remember where, so I could give them the credit.  8-)

I assign an `id` to each of my pages (or all the pages within a section) like this:

```
In index.html:    <body id='section-intro'>...
In faq.html:      <body id='section-faq'>...
In download.html: <body id='section-download'>...
```

And then an `id` for the corresponding links:

```
<li id='nav-intro'><a href="./">Introduction</a></li>
<li id='nav-faq'><a href="./faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
<li id='nav-download'><a href="./download.html">Download</a></li>
```

And the in the CSS I set a rule like this:

```
#section-intro #nav-intro,
#section-faq #nav-faq,
#section-download #nav-download {
    font-weight: bold;
    /* And whatever other styles the current link should have. */
}
```

So this works in a mostly declarative way to control the style of the link that the current page belongs in.  You can see it in action here: http://entrian.com/source-search/

It's a very clean and simple system once you've set it up, because:

- You don't need to mess about with template markup in your links
- You don't end up using big ugly `switch` statements or `if / else / else` statements
- Adding pages to a section Just Works [TM]
- Changing the way things look only ever means changing the CSS, not the markup.

I'm not using Django, but this system works anywhere.  In your case, where you "set their own respective titles and contents" you also need to set the `body id`, and there's no other Django markup required.

This idea extends easily to other situations as well, eg. "I want a download link in the sidebar on every page except the download pages themselves."  You can do that in CSS like this:

```
#section-download #sidebar #download-link {
    display: none;
}
```

rather than having to put conditional template markup in the sidebar HTML.

Comment: Doesn't this mean a lot of duplicated content in the CSS though?

Comment: ...I mean the style for each link id.

Comment: It's one line of CSS for each page/section.  The style itself only appears once, with a comma-separated list of section/nav pairs before it.

Comment: I first found about this technique from here: http://24ways.org/2005/auto-selecting-navigation

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used Django, but I've dealt with the same issue in [Kohana](http://kohanaphp.com/) (PHP) and Rails.

What I do in Kohana:

```
<li><a href="/admin/dashboard" <?= (get_class($this) == 'Dashboard_Controller') ? "class=\"active\"" : NULL ?>>Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="/admin/campaigns" <?= (get_class($this) == 'Campaigns_Controller') ? "class=\"active\"" : NULL ?>>Campaigns</a></li>
<li><a href="/admin/lists" <?= (get_class($this) == 'Lists_Controller') ? "class=\"active\"" : NULL ?>>Lists</a></li>
```

What I do in Rails:

```
<li><a href="/main" <%= 'class="active"' if (controller.controller_name == 'main') %>>Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="/notifications" <%= 'class="active"' if (controller.controller_name == 'notifications') %>>Notifications</a></li>
<li><a href="/reports" <%= 'class="active"' if (controller.controller_name == 'reports') %>>Reports</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see only a couple of ways of doing it, while avoiding repeated ifequals:

1. Javascript. Something along the lines of (jQuery):

   ```
   var parts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
   var page = parts[parts.length-1];
   $('#sidebar1 a[href*=' + page + ']').addClass('current');
   ```
2. Change your views to contain a list of pages with their associated titles and URLs and create a {% for %} loop in your template, which will go through that list, and add a single {% ifequal %}.

Option 2 being the favorite from where I stand. If the logic for all of your pages is the same, and only the templates differ, you might consider using the FlatPages model for each of your pages. If the logic is different, and you need different models, you might consider using a menuing app of some sort. A shameless plug: I have a [menuing app of my own](http://code.google.com/p/django-yama/)

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `request` context processor, it's pretty straightforward:

```
settings.py:

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'  # admin app wants this too
)
```

Now you have access to the `HttpRequest`, which contains the request path. Highlighting the current page is a simple matter of checking if the path matches the link's destination, i.e., you're already there:

```
<li><a class="{% if request.path == '/' %}current{% endif %}" href="/">Index</a></li>
<li><a class="{% if request.path == '/stuff/' %}current{% endif %}" href="/stuff/">Stuff</a></li>
<li><a class="{% if request.path == '/about/' %}current{% endif %}" href="/about/">About Me</a></li>
<li><a class="{% if request.path == '/contact/' %}current{% endif %}" href="/contact/">Contact Me</a></li>
```