# Is there a way to pass a variable to an 'extended' template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to add some flexibility to my layout template, but I can't find any way to do so.

I'm looking for a way to `extend` my layout template with variable, i.e. to pass a variable up in the template tree, not down.

```
# views.py
def my_view_func(request):
    return render(request, "child.html")
```

---

```
# child.html
{% extends 'layout.html' with show_sidebar=True sidebar_width_class="width_4" %}

<div>Templates stuff here</div>
```

---

```
# layout.html
{% if show_sidebar %}
    <div class="{{ sidebar_width_class }}">
        {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I have to maintain four templates with a difference in a few lines of code. For example, I have two templates that differ from each other by a sidebar width class. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @xpy, nope. In my question, I'm looking for a way to extend layout template with variable, i.e. to pass variable up in the template tree not down.

Comment: Sorry,  misunderstood.

Comment: Why won't you pass your variables with context `render(request, "child.html", {'sidebar_width': "width_4"})` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I suspect that `block` is what you are looking for in the first place.

Form your block inside the base template like this:

```
{% block sidebar_wrapper %}
    {% if sidebar %}
    <div class="width{{sidebar_width}}">
        {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock sidebar_wrapper%}
```

And on your child template:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block sidebar_wrapper %}
    {% with sidebar=True sidebar_width=4 %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endwith%}
{% endblock sidebar_wrapper%}
```

Comment: nope.. your example is about passing variables down. When we rendering templates and extending layout we haven't such possibility.

Comment: I have updated my question, hope now it would be more clear.

Comment: @AlexT how is this "down"? The `sidebar_wrapper` is in the parent template and in the child template, you define which values to use in the block of the parent template with the `with` statement.

Comment: Did this works for you? I have tested your solution and both `sidebar_width` and `sidebar` is blank in `layout.html`

Comment: @AlexT yes, it did. I didn't test it with nested block though. I tested it with the `sidebar_wrapper` on the base template and the `with` statement inside a template that extends a template that extends the base template.

Comment: I have tested your example yesterday and it doesn't work. I will try once more but it seems that you can't pass variables to extended block with `with` statement.

Comment: @AlexT I stumbled upon this thread while doing research about it if it is of any help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/-yx5QjjCNS0

Comment: I found what's wrong with your example. `{% with %}` statement should be placed in the block (not out). Fix it.

Comment: Amazing. It saved me a lot of time! Thank you. Nice trick!

Comment: @xpy thanks, buddy. first time I found to know that we can do something like that in django for passing variables to the parent's template.

Answer (score 13):

What you need is an include template tag. You can include a template in another template and render that with specific context.

```
{% include 'layout.html' with sidebar=True sidebar_width=4 %}
```

Check docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: I want to extend template, not to include it.

Comment: Your sidebar part looks like a snippet and it's configurable via a context, so why not keep the sidebar snippet into a template and include it in other templates with specific context? You should think that sidebar is a common configurable template, not extend from it.

Comment: sidebar definitely is, what about layout templates without sidebar?

f.e. I have pages with sidebar width3, width4 and without sidebar at all. Content part of this three layouts differ from each other and content part markup is quite complicated to include it each time in {% block content %}

Comment: Maybe have a parent template with {% include 'layout.html' with sidebar=sidebar sidebar_width=sidebar_width %} and send those values from backend in context if you need to be more dynamic?

Comment: I'm thinking now about double extending.


Main layout with common for all site markup (head, header, footer)

Secondary layout with {%block content%} markup 

But it still have issues, because I've used bootstrap like css framework. When I'm declaring sidebar width 3, I must to declare content width {{maxwidh}}-3 as well.

Comment: Had to change my `extends` by `includes` for this to work. Don't really get what the side effects might be but since it's just for one page I don't care much.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with some technique. I'll show the code then explain below.

```
# layout.html

{% block content %}
    {% if show_sidebar %}
        <div class="{{ sidebar_width_class }}">
            {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

```
# child.html

{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% with show_sidebar=True sidebar_width_class="width_4" %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

- In `layout.html`, wrap everything inside `{% block content %}`
- In `child.html`, `{{ block.super }}` is like python's `super()`, which renders everything in the parent template's block. So if you wrap it inside `{% with %}` tag, all variables that you declare there will be available inside the parent template as well.